# Convert binary to varchar on button click

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a registration page for an SQL server, and I have some problems when it comes to the login section. The column Passphrase is set to dataType Binary(20). When a user registers an account from my form it enters their password in the Passphrase column as .

```
insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passphrase", System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(TextBoxPass.Text));
```

When I create a Password using the default stored procedure for creating accounts it sets the password in the Passphrase column as "NULL".

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_HashPassphrase2](
@vchPassphrase varchar(12),
@intAccountID int
)
RETURNS binary(20)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN (
    HASHBYTES('md5',@vchPassphrase)
);
END
```

When I try to log into an account that was created with the registration page I get password mismatch.

My question is this...

When someone enters their account info into the login fields, how can I convert the  back into varchar(12) when the login button is clicked?

Here is my button click

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegDNMembershipConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();
    string cmdStr = "select count(*) from Accounts where AccountName='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
    SqlCommand Checkuser = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(Checkuser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        string cmdStr2="Select Passphrase from Accounts where AccountName='" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand pass=new SqlCommand(cmdStr2, con);
        string password=pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        con.Close();
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but you have a big SQL injection problem. Look at parameterizing your queries. For example if I enter something like `';DROP DATABASE MASTER--` as the account name (TextBox1) will delete your master database (DONT TRY IT). Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: I am removing your `mysql` tag as this is obviously `Microsoft SQL Server`

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, as you haven't shown the actual code for comparing the passwords to the user entered text. I am assuming that you are trying to compare invalid data against each other. It is also worth noting that comparing binary will be `Case Sensitive`. (Yes I know binary doesnt have any concept of case sensitivity for the binary content).

The process I would take (if I had to use this example) is using a SP to create the user account and setting the binary passphrase using your existing function something like. *(note this is quite basic and doesnt check if an account already exists).*

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_CreateUser]
    @AccountName nvarchar(50),
    @Passphrase nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Passbinary binary(20) = (SELECT [dbo].[FN_HashPassphrase2](@Passphrase))
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accounts] (AccountName, Passphrase) VALUES (@AccountName, @Passbinary)
END
```

Then create the user on your form such as...

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CON_String"].ConnectionString))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_CreateUser @p0, @p1", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", Username.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Password.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Now that gives us a result such as (yes basic).
[image]

So we now have the correct data in the database. Now for checking the user account I would use another stored procedure passing in the plain text of the `AccountName` and `Passpharse` using your existing hashing function to compare the password binary strings such as.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_VerifyUser
    @AccountName nvarchar(50),
    @Passphrase nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Passbinary binary(20) = (SELECT [dbo].[FN_HashPassphrase2](@Passphrase))
    DECLARE @AccountID int = (SELECT TOP 1 AccountID FROM [dbo].[Accounts] WHERE AccountName = @AccountName AND Passphrase = @Passbinary)
    SELECT TOP 1 CAST(CASE WHEN @AccountID IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE @AccountID END as INT)
END
GO
```

This simple SP will return a int (the account number) if the user exists by matching the account name and binary converted passphrase. If there isnt a match then -1 will be returned otherwise the accountID will be. Then from your code this is simple to call such as.

```
errorLbl.Text = "";
using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CON_String"].ConnectionString))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_VerifyUser @p0, @p1", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", Username.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Password.Text);
    con.Open();
    var accountID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    con.Close();
    if (accountID == -1)
        errorLbl.Text = "Username and password mismatch";
    else
    {
        errorLbl.Text = "YOUR GOOD TO GO! Have a nice day.. Your account ID is:" + accountID;
    }
}
```

As you can see this is quite a simple example.

**What this will do**

1. Binary store the password using a MD5 hash function
2. Compare user plain text username and password against a stored record calling the same hash function above

**What this is missing**

1. All your other account fields were not taken into consideration
2. Does not represent your actual database architecture.