# Insert auto increment

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a method `Insert()`. Everything is working as expected except for the auto increment. Here's the code:

```
public void Insert(string m1,int y1,int new_count)
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO page_counter (id,month,year,page_count) VALUES('','"+m1+"',"+y1+","+new_count+")";

            //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

            //Execute command
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //close connection
            this.CloseConnection();
    }
```

My Id column is an auto-increment. So my question is how can the value be inserted in the database an continue the auto increment in the table for id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is exclude the auto-incremented `IDENTITY` column from your insert.

Change your `query` to:

```
//NOTE: We leave the "id" column out of the insert, SQL Server will handle this automatically
string query = "INSERT INTO page_counter (month, year, page_count) VALUES (@Month, @Year, @PageCount)";
```

SQL will take care of the ID field.

You might notice I used Scalar variables in my query.  You can (and should) assign these in the command so that you exclude the possibility of SQL injection:

**EDIT DUE TO THE FACT THAT THIS IS COMING FROM MySql.Data.MySqlClient PRE 4.0**

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Month", m1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Year", y1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@PageCount", new_count));

//Execute the INSERT
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

For a little background on SQL Injection I would recommend reading:

1. [SQL Injection on W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)
2. [Why use Parameterized SQL on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection)

Comment: can you tell me logically what is actually the difference between my method and using the @ sign?

Comment: In your method, someone can inject malicious code directly into the value `m1` or `y1`.  Consider if they wrote this into wherever you are getting `m1`:  `'; DROP TABLE USERS;`  Your code would literally execute that code on the server because the malicious user *appended text to your string*.  Using Parametarized SQL you ensure that no one can insert SQL commands directly into the query.  You take the query away from a string literal and treat Data like data rather than text.

Comment: @Ren the above should give you a little insight, and I added a couple links in my answer.  It takes a little more typing, but overall, parametarized sql will save you security problems AND many syntax / datatype errors when you start using more complex INSERTS/UPDATES.  Also sql injection can occur on even the most innocuous queries like: `SELECT customer_id FROM customer` etc...

Comment: owh ok. So where should I place the cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()? because if i place it under MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection), it display error "no extension method AddWithValue accepting first argument.."

Comment: It should go under the `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand` block but before `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`.  The syntax is as follows `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MyParameter", theValueIWantToAssign);`  Make sure you have quotes around the `@Parameter`.  If you literally copy/paste my code it should work.

Comment: yeah, I copy paste your code. and it just display the error at AddWithValue. Not sure why.below is the error message.

Comment: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: My guess is you have a type somewhere.  Try using Intellisense.  Just start typing cmd.Para and you should see Parameters.  Then type `.AddWi` and you should see `AddWithValue(string,object)`;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49860/discussion-between-ren-and-evan-l)

Comment: @Ren OOOHHH  Ok, probably different syntax for `MySql`.  Try `cmd.Parameters.Add("@Parameter").Value(m1);` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Simply don't specify value for `id` :

```
string query = "INSERT INTO page_counter (month,year,page_count) VALUES('"+m1+"',"+y1+","+new_count+")";
```

And look into better approach, parameterized query, instead of concatenating query string.

Answer (score 3):

[Using AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)

No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO page_counter (month,year,page_count)
VALUES('"+m1+"',"+y1+","+new_count+")";
```

You can always use Parameterized query to avoid [**SQL Injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection)

```
string query = "INSERT INTO page_counter (month,year,page_count)
VALUES(@month,@year,@page_count)";

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@month",Value1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", Value2);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@page_count", Value3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string query = "INSERT INTO page_counter (month,year,page_count) VALUES('"+m1+"',"+y1+","+new_count+")";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 1):

You can change identity of id in database

```
"INSERT INTO page_counter (month,year,page_count) VALUES('"+m1+"',"+y1+","+new_count+")"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not specify ID from here:

If you are using SQL Server, have your ID field in your DB created like so:

`ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY`

If MySQL then:

`ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`

Look at the following link: 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp