# Error :check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: c#, mysql

I am having a problem with this. I want to update a record in my database but, It keeps showing this message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'values='85' WHERE stud_no='2014-0317-TSF-1'' at line 1

```
string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=";
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
string Query = "UPDATE stud_grades.firstyear_firstgrading SET values='" + valuesTextBox.Text + "' WHERE stud_no='" + stud_noTextBox.Text + "';";
MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
myConn.Open();
SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Questions should not contain tags in their title. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VALUES` is a reserved MySQL word: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Either rename this field or include `values` in back-ticks: `

Answer (score 4):

Use backticks for `values` bacause it is a keyword

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Always use parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection

[How does SQLParameter prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection)

```
string Query = "UPDATE stud_grades.firstyear_firstgrading SET `values`=@values where 
                                stud_no=@stud_no";
MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(Query, myConn);
SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@values ", valuesTextBox.Text);
SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stud_no", stud_noTextBox.Text);
myConn.Open();
SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: +1 for going the extra mile and actually showing the _correct_ way of forming SQL queries in .net