# Connecting to database

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I'm getting a run time error in my program when connecting to a SQL Server CE database.

Can anyone help me, and please don't write the whole code just a line of what needs to be changed to.

Here is my code:

```
string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.POSdatabaseConnectionString;

using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer where Customer ID ='" + this.useridtexbox.Text + "' and Name='" + this.nametexbox.Text + "'", con))
    {
        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("You have logged in succesfully");
           Homepage homepage = new Homepage();
           homepage.Show();
           homepage.LabelText = ("Welcome " + reader["name"].ToString());
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Username and password is Not correct ...Please try again");
           con.Close();
        }
```

Error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 39,Token in error = ID ]

Comment: When asking for help, don't tell us how to help you.

Comment: Also, you've left yourself wide open to sql injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command, do not use string concatenation. That will fail badly and leave you open to SQL injection attacks.

Image what happens if I enter the following text into `this.nametexbox.Text`:

> Joe'; DROP DATABASE; --

You don't want have someone like [little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) as user.

Use sql parameters.

If you have tables or fields with spaces, you to have a word with your DBA. If you cannot change it, make sure you use the correct syntax:

```
WHERE [Customer ID] = '12345'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem with the space in Customer ID,Try this

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM Customer where CustomerID ='" +    this.useridtexbox.Text + "' and Name='" + this.nametexbox.Text + "'", con))
```

Comment: or [Customer ID] if there truly is a space in that field.  also- this code is wide open for sql injection attacks.  you need to escape the user input:  this.nametexbox.Text.Replace("'", "''")

Comment: @jdanyow Yes you are correct,but i answered for the exception what OP was getting

Comment: @NullReferenceException i get this error: The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = ,Column name = CustomerID ]

Comment: @user3439080 follow the approach as answered by nvoigt,and check the Column name in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you `CustomerID` column have space

Always use parameterized query to avoid SQL Injection

[How does SQLParameter prevent SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection)

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand = "SELECT * FROM Customer where CustomerID=@CustomerID and  
                                name=@name";
con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", valuesTextBox.Text);
con.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", namwTextBox.Text);
```