# check the manual that corresponds to you mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '(CourseId = 'mect211')

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax-error

I am writing a student database program on C# using MySql. I want to update the information but it's always giving me that error. Here is the program I wrote.

```
private void Update_bttn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConString = " datasource = localhost; port = 3306; username = root; password = 3306";
    string Query = " Update studentdata.studentrecord set (CourseId = '" + this.crsId.Text + "', CourseName = '" + this.crsName.Text + "',Credits = '" + this.credits.Text + "', CourseStatement = '" + this.CrseStatment.Text + "',Grade = '" + this.Grades.Text + "' where CourseId = '" + this.crsId.Text+"' ; ";
    MySqlConnection ConDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString);
    MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(Query, ConDatabase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    try
    {
        ConDatabase.Open();
        myReader = cmdDataBase.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show("Information Updated");
        while ((myReader.Read())) { }
        ConDatabase.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
}
```

Comment: You are opening a bracket `(CourseId` but not closing it anywhere in your code. Do not concatenate queries, use Parameters. Your current code is prone to SQL Injection.

Comment: @Habib, that's an answer.

Comment: i have put the )" but still the same output :s any other advice plz ?

Comment: Use the debugger to grab the actual value of `Querry` before you execute it.  Grab the value of it and try to execute that command directly against your Database.  That should give you a more detailed error at least

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, you can grab the value of `query` through debugging and attempt to run the actual query in SQL to get a more precise error. In this case however, it is because you have an open parentheses `(CourseId...` and no close `)` later in the string.

Also, you may want to look into some [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) surrounding your use of the `Sql` classes in C#

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterized query to avoid SQL injection

[How does SQLParameter prevent SQL Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection)

you have `(` near `CourseId`

```
string query = update studentdata.studentrecord set CourseId =@CourseId,CourseName=@CourseName,Credits =@Credits,CourseStatement=@CourseStatement,Grade =@Grade  where CourseId =@CourseId";

MySqlConnection ConDatabase = new MySqlConnection(ConString);

MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand(query, ConDatabase);

cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseId",this.crsId.Text );
cmdDataBase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseName", this.crsName.Text);
```

and so on

Comment: hey thank you ! when i'm using you're code the compiler is telling me : "Fatal error encountered during command execution." any help ?

Comment: you have to add this way for other values like CourseStatement

Comment: i didn't understand what you mean... plz explain to me