# how to prevent bug/error when saving data with the same primary key on visual basic 2012?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i'm using visual studio 2012 and microsoft SQL server 2012 to make a save function.

my coding is like this:

form:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        If Len(Trim(txt_nis.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_nisn.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_namasiswa.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(cmb_kelaminsiswa.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_kotalahir.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(DTP_siswa.Value)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(cmb_agamasiswa.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_beratsiswa.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_tinggisiswa.Text)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Data Belum Lengkap")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ClassSiswa.Nis = txt_nis.Text
        ClassSiswa.Nisn = txt_nisn.Text
        ClassSiswa.Nama_Siswa = txt_namasiswa.Text
        ClassSiswa.Jenis_Kelamin = cmb_kelaminsiswa.Text
        ClassSiswa.Kota_Lahir = txt_kotalahir.Text
        ClassSiswa.Tanggal_Lahir = DTP_siswa.Value
        ClassSiswa.Agama = cmb_agamasiswa.Text
        ClassSiswa.Berat_Badan = txt_beratsiswa.Text
        ClassSiswa.Tinggi_Badan = txt_tinggisiswa.Text
        ClassSiswa.RekamData(ClassSiswa.opencon)
        MsgBox("Data siswa Berhasil Disimpan")
        datagridview()
    End Sub
```

class

```
Public Shared Sub RekamData(ByVal _Cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection)
        Dim sql As SqlClient.SqlCommand
        sql = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
        sql.Connection = _Cn
        sql.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sql.CommandText = "Insert into siswa values('" & Nis & "','" & Nisn & "','" & Nama_Siswa & "','" & Jenis_Kelamin & "','" & Kota_Lahir & "','" & Tanggal_Lahir & "','" & Agama & "','" & Berat_Badan & "','" & Tinggi_Badan & "')"
        sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
```

SQL query:

```
Create Table siswa 
(
Nis varchar (40) primary key,
Nisn varchar (40),
Nama_Siswa varchar(40),
Jenis_Kelamin varchar (10),
Kota_Lahir varchar (10),
Tanggal_Lahir date,
Agama varchar (10),
Berat_Badan varchar (10),
Tinggi_Badan varchar (10)
)
```

Nis is primary key.

in the windows form datagridview there is a data that i already saved with Nis : 123, if i saved another data with the same Nis : 123 the program will stop and give me a error because there is already Nis with the value 123.

what i wanted to do is:

instead of  show me the error, i want to make a coding that show me a messagebox "data already saved" so that the program won't stopped beacuse of error.

how do i make a coding to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to update the record when it already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RekamData` method will throw a `SqlException` with exception number `2627` if the primary key is duplicated. Catch it in your `btnSave_Click` method:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    If Len(Trim(txt_nis.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_nisn.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_namasiswa.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(cmb_kelaminsiswa.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_kotalahir.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(DTP_siswa.Value)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(cmb_agamasiswa.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_beratsiswa.Text)) = 0 Or Len(Trim(txt_tinggisiswa.Text)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Data Belum Lengkap")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ClassSiswa.Nis = txt_nis.Text
    ClassSiswa.Nisn = txt_nisn.Text
    ClassSiswa.Nama_Siswa = txt_namasiswa.Text
    ClassSiswa.Jenis_Kelamin = cmb_kelaminsiswa.Text
    ClassSiswa.Kota_Lahir = txt_kotalahir.Text
    ClassSiswa.Tanggal_Lahir = DTP_siswa.Value
    ClassSiswa.Agama = cmb_agamasiswa.Text
    ClassSiswa.Berat_Badan = txt_beratsiswa.Text
    ClassSiswa.Tinggi_Badan = txt_tinggisiswa.Text
    Try
        ClassSiswa.RekamData(ClassSiswa.opencon)
        datagridview()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        If ex.Number = 2627 Then
            MsgBox("Duplicate key")
        Else
            MsgBox("SQL exception " & ex.Message)
        End If
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    ' Sorry - I don't know what this means :)
    MsgBox("Data siswa Berhasil Disimpan")
End Sub
```

Comment: the `MsgBox("Data siswa Berhasil Disimpan")` is to confirm that all data has been saved.

Comment: i tried the coding and it worked. the only problem is when i finished saving the data, the messagebox `MsgBox("Data siswa Berhasil Disimpan")` doesn't show up to notice me that all the data has been saved.

Comment: Sorry - I made a mistake and commented out the `MsgBox` in my code. I've fixed it. I also made a change where the duplicate key is caught: if you have some other kind of SQL exception that should also be reported, and after the exception reporting I added an `Exit Sub`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use query which insert rows only if new Primary Key value doesn't exist in the table

```sql
INSERT INTO siswa VALUES 
(SELECT @Nis
, @Nisn
, @Nama_Siswa
, @Jenis_Kelamin
, @Kota_Lahir
, @Tanggal_Lahir
, @Agama
, @Berat_Badan
, @Tinggi_Badan 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM siswa WHERE Nis = @Nis))
```

I think checking for existed primary keys is job for the function which insert new row.
Based on method `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` which return number of the affected rows
You can change Sub `RekamData` to Function that return true of row inserted or false if not.

```vb
Public Shared Function RekamData(ByVal _Cn As SqlClient.SqlConnection) As Boolean
    Dim query As String = "here copy query above"
    Dim insertedQnt As Int32
    Using sqlcom As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, _Cn)
        sqlcom.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        With Sql.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@Nis", Nis)
            .AddWithValue("@Nisn", Nisn)
            .AddWithValue("@Nama_Siswa", Nama_Siswa)
            .AddWithValue("@Jenis_Kelamin", Jenis_Kelamin)
            .AddWithValue("@Kota_Lahir", Kota_Lahir)
            .AddWithValue("@Tanggal_Lahir", Tanggal_Lahir)
            .AddWithValue("@Agama", Agama)
            .AddWithValue("@Berat_Badan", Berat_Badan)
            .AddWithValue("@Tinggi_Badan", Tinggi_Badan)
        End With
        insertedQnt = sqlcom.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    Return (insertedQnt > 0)
End Function
```

Then use it

```vb
'your code
If ClassSiswa.RekamData(ClassSiswa.opencon) = True Then
    MsgBox("Data siswa Berhasil Disimpan")
Else
    MsgBox("Value of Nis already exist")
End If
```

In the example I used `SqlParameter` for passing values to the database query.
I think this is good practice to use parameters.
For example parameters will help with problem of [Sql Injection](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)
[How-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection)