# Trying the read data from one table then write it to another table

Tags: c#, web-services, ms-access

I am try to inset data into another table from the first table. I pass 2 things from the Website to the [WebMethod].

```
[WebMethod]
public string purchaseInfo(int itemID, string logedInEmail)
```

When i run this an exception is thrown saying

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression".

```
 try
       {
           OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
           conn.Open();

           OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
           cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ItemID, itemName, description, price FROM ItemInfo WHERE (ItemID = '" + itemID + "')"; //ItemID is a AutoNumber field.
           OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

           while (reader.Read()) // Reading the data selected
           {
               int currentItemID = (int)reader["ItemID"];                   
               string currentItemName = (string)reader["itemName"];
               string currentdescription = (string)reader["description"];
               string currentPrice = (string)reader["price"];

               cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo (itemID, buyerIDEmail, itemName, description, price)
                                 VALUES ('" + currentItemID + "', '" + logedInEmail + "', '" + currentItemName + "', '" + currentdescription + "', '" + currentPrice + "')";
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                   
           }

           conn.Close();
           return "Successful";

       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           return ex.Message;
       }
```

I have checked if all the data fields are the correct type in the database, and as far as I can tell they are.
currentItemID is inserted into Number field.
and the rest is all inserted into a Short Text field.

Don't know if it matter but there is also an Auto number field in PurchaseInfo.

Comment: Oh no! Do not create SQL statements like that. Guard yourself against [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Why two steps? Why not create a query that selects from ItemInfo and inserts in purchaseinfo with any extra data as parameters?

Comment: Wait how does this look? I am quite new to this stuff

Comment: ok figured it out, thanx for the help. Never new i could just do that XD.

Answer (score 0):

> `currentItemID` is inserted into `Number` field.

I think that's the problem since you try to insert it with single quotes as `'" + currentItemID + "'`. Remove single quotes between them.

Also `ItemID = '" + itemID + "'` looks suspicious to me. Based on it's name, this should be some numerical values as well. So, you *might* need to remove these single quotes as well.

But more important, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection, command and reader automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

```
using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
      // Set your CommandText property.
      // Add parameters with `Add` method
      using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
          while (reader.Read())
          {
               // Get your values.
               // Clear your parameters with `Parameters.Clear()` method.
               // Add new parameters to `cmd`
               // Execute your query.
          }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameterize queries like so:

```
try
{
   OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
   conn.Open();

   OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ItemID, itemName, description, price FROM ItemInfo WHERE (ItemID = @itemId)";
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@itemId", itemId)
   OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   while (reader.Read()) // Reading the data selected
   {
       int currentItemID = (int)reader["ItemID"];                   
       string currentItemName = (string)reader["itemName"];
       string currentDescription = (string)reader["description"];
       string currentPrice = (string)reader["price"];

       cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO PurchaseInfo (itemID, buyerIDEmail, itemName, description, price)
                         VALUES (@currentItemId, @loggedInEmail, @currentItemName, @currentDescription,@currentPrice)";
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@currentItemId", currentItemId);
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@loggedInEmail", loggedInEmail);
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@currentItemName", currentItemName);
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@currentDescription", currentDescription);
       cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@currentPrice", currentPrice);
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();                   
   }

   conn.Close();
   return "Successful";

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return ex.Message;
}
```

Comment: I tried changing it to that but it still throws the Exception

Comment: ok wait got it to not throw that exception. but it now says, "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."