# How do I send a date time picker value to SQL local database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, date, datetime

So the thing is, im trying to insert 2 dates into my local database using c#, the date values are taken from 2 different datetimepickers called dtp1 and dtp2 but i dont know how to do that, i tried the following:

```
connect.Open();
command = new SqlCommand("insert into ab (id, name, data1, data2) values ("+int.Parse(textbox_id.Text)+", '"+textBox_name.Text+"', "+dtp1.Value+","+dtp2.Value+")",connect);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect.Close();
```

The error is : incorrect syntax

Comment: What is the complete error message exactly? What is your column types? And you should _always_ use parameterized statements. This kind of string concatenations are open for SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: Have you ever heard about parameterized queries?

Answer (score 2):

First let's fix the SQL injection vulnerability in your code.  Create a query with parameters:

```
command = new SqlCommand("insert into ab (id, name, data1, data2) values (@id, @name, @data1, @data2)",connect);
```

Then you can simply add values for those parameters, without having to worry about their string representations (rendering your current problem moot):

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(textbox_id.Text));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox_name.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data1", dtp1.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data2", dtp2.Value);
```

The benefits here include:

- Much cleaner and easier to read code
- You can use values as-is rather than trying to convert them to specific string representations
- Most importantly, you're treating user input as *values* rather than as *executable code*

Comment: Thanks!  I did just as you said and i understood now and it works.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `SqlParameter` to be sure no sql injection is possible: [How does SQLParameter prevent SQL Injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection).
2. If you use string concation, try to use `string.Format` to get things more clear: `string.Format("insert into ab (id, name, data1, data2) values ({0}, '{1}', {2}, {3})", textbox_id.Text, textBox_name.Text, dtp1.Value, dtp2.Value)`. But in general this is not a good idea to pass parameter.
3. Why do you use `int.parse` if you make a `ToString` later when concation? This is not needed: `("+int.Parse(textbox_id.Text)+",`. This is the same like this: `("+(int.Parse(textbox_id.Text)).ToString()+",` which is the same like: `textbox_id.Text`. Besides it throws an exception if `textbox_id.Text` does not contains some thing that could be parsed into an integer. If you want to check for integer, just use `int.TryParse`.
4. You may get some syntax error if `dtp1.Value` or `dtp2.Value` is empty or if you try to pass some thing besides integer.

> Using `SqlParamter` for DateTime even has the advantagem that you don't have to care about the `DateTime` format. Which can be really annoying.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i used sqlparameters and also edited the id just as you said.