# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the connection class:

```
public string InsertarTecnico(int IdNumTecnico, string NombresTecnico, string ApellidosTecnico, string DireccionTecnico, string TelefonoTecnico, string ProvinciaTecnico, string CiudadTecnico, string TipoTecnico, string FechaTecnico)
    {
        string salida = "Datos guardados";

        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into TECNICO(NUMIDTECNICO, NOMBRETECNICO, APELLIDOTECNICO, DIRECCIONTECNICO, TELEFONOTECNICO, PROVINCIATECNICO, CIUDADTECNICO, FECHAYHORATECNICO, TIPO) values(" + IdNumTecnico + ", '" + NombresTecnico + "', '" + ApellidosTecnico + "', '" + DireccionTecnico + "', '"+TelefonoTecnico+"', '" + ProvinciaTecnico + "', '"+CiudadTecnico+"', '" + TipoTecnico + "', '" + FechaTecnico + "')", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FechaTecnico", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            salida = "No se puedo duardar los datos... " + ex.ToString();
        }
        return salida;
    }
```

This is the control code:

```
private void SaveTechnicalButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Conex.TecnicoRegistrado(Convert.ToInt32(IdTechnical.Text))==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Conex.InsertarTecnico(Convert.ToInt32(IdTechnical.Text), NameTechnical.Text, LastNameTechnical.Text, AdressTechnical.Text, PhoneTechnical.Text, ProvinceTechnical.Text, CityTechnical.Text, SelectChiefTechnical.Text, DateTime.Parse(DateEnterTechnical.Text)));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("La persona que intenta ingresar ya se encuentra registrada");
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up0Ty.png)

The problem is conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Please remove unnecessary codes but post your question with a [MCVE]

Comment: And please provide the concrete exception with all details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the arguments are incorrect:

```
MessageBox.Show(Conex.InsertarTecnico(Convert.ToInt32(IdTechnical.Text), NameTechnical.Text, LastNameTechnical.Text, AdressTechnical.Text, PhoneTechnical.Text, CityTechnical.Text, ProvinceTechnical.Text, PhoneTechnical.Text, DateEnterTechnical.Text));

InsertarTecnico(int IdNumTecnico, string NombresTecnico, string ApellidosTecnico, string DireccionTecnico, string TelefonoTecnico, string ProvinciaTecnico, string CiudadTecnico, string FechaTecnico, string TipoTecnico)
```

You are passing DateEnterTechnical to TipoTecnico and twice TelefonoTechnico

The order seem to be:

```
MessageBox.Show(Conex.InsertarTecnico(Convert.ToInt32(IdTechnical.Text), NameTechnical.Text, LastNameTechnical.Text, AdressTechnical.Text, PhoneTechnical.Text, ProvinceTechnical.Text, CityTechnical.Text, DateTime.Parse(DateEnterTechnical.Text), tipoTecnico));
```

Make sure to parse the DateEnterTechnical to DateTime:

```
DateTime.Parse(DateEnterTechnical.Text)
```

Also, your code is subject to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Considering using [SqlParameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection).

Comment: I corrected the duplicate entries, added DateTime.Parse(DateEnterTechnical.Text) without any results, adding DateTime.Parse(DateEnterTechnical.Text), I generates an error in the compilation (cannot convert from 'System.DateTime' to 'string')

Comment: This is because your method `InsertarTecnico` takes a string. Change it to: InsertarTecnico(int IdNumTecnico, string NombresTecnico, string ApellidosTecnico, string DireccionTecnico, string TelefonoTecnico, string ProvinciaTecnico, string CiudadTecnico, DateTime FechaTecnico, string TipoTecnico)

Comment: compilation pass but pressing the button generates save me error: Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll ("Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string")
Exception: Exception caught: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll ("Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string")

Comment: Now that happens because you are concatenating the DateTime with a string, which calls ToString in it. Please consider using the SqlParameters as I mentioned (specially to avoid SQL injections

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly reformat text that is taken from `DateEnterTechnical.Text` control and passed to `InsertarTecnico` function as the last argument `string TipoTecnico` - as your date cannot be recognized by the database.

Ideally, you should

- use some kind of calendar control on your form, to get a date from control, not a string
- if you are getting a string, then parse it as date using, for example [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) with a specific **format string**
- format your date into [ODBC canonical form](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) when creating insert statement
- remove direct usage of SQL queries from code, and replace it with a stored procedure, and [pass parameters to your command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)