# how to use Gridview

Tags: c#, mysql, webforms

I have a webform where I can display data from a mysql database on a page with a gridview. I have placed a Textbox on the webform, which I would like to search among database records.

```
 string mysqlconnectionstring = "Server=server;Database=dataser;Uid=user;Pwd=passw;CharSet=utf8";
 MySqlConnection MyConnection = new MySqlConnection(mysqlconnectionstring);
 string query = "select * from Tools where NameofTool like '" + Search_txt.Text + "%'";
 MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, MyConnection);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 GridView1_0.DataSource = ds;
 GridView1_0.DataBind();
```

So, if I understand the problem of extracting all the data from a datasource at the beginning, and then I want to give it the search. Of course I can interpret it wrong, sorry.

So the goal would be to get data from a DataSource, run it out with a GridView, then update the GridView according to the results.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dt2.Rows.Clear();
cn.Open();
string comm = "SELECT * From Ansprechperson WHERE Name LIKE '%'+ @Firma + '%' AND KundenNr LIKE @KundenNr";
cmd = new SqlCeCommand(comm, cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Firma", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = editContactFilter.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@KundenNr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = KundenNr;
using (adapt = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd))
{
     adapt.Fill(dt2);
}
dataGridView2.DataSource = dt2;
cn.Close();
```

This is an example that worked for me. Please look into parameters to make your application SQL-Injection safe. [Why Parameters protect you from SQL-Injection.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection)

dt2 is a DataTable:
        `DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();`

Answer (score -1):

ideal approach would be search precise data from sql insdead first get all the data in data set and go for an other search.

kindly dont use inline queries like

```
string query = "select * from Tools where NameofTool like '" + Search_txt.Text + "%'";
```

instead use stored procedures. these inline queries are prone to sql injection.

so your ans would be "create a stored procedure with filter parameter"
and then bind GridView with returned data.

Comment: You don't need to use stored procedures to avoid Sql injection, using command parameters is fine. And this doesn't answer the question anyway.