# Error near Where Clause in ASP NET

Tags: c#, sql-server

Below is a code and Visual Studio is raising error that there is syntax error near WHERE.

```
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insert into courses(t_id_fk) values('" + valu3 + "') where c_id=@dr1 ", con);
cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@dr1", SqlDbType.Int);
                cmd2.Parameters["@dr1"].Value = d1;
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

Comment: Does your table have a column `c_id`?

Comment: what exactly is the error?

Comment: Do not concatenate valu3 in like that. It is a **very bad idea**. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove where clause while inserting:

**from:**

```
"insert into courses(t_id_fk) values('" + valu3 + "') where c_id=@dr1 "
```

**to:**

```
"insert into courses(t_id_fk) values('" + valu3 + "')"
```

But if the sample given above is an `update` then:

```
 "update courses set t_id_fk = '" + valu3 + "'  where c_id=@dr1"
```

Comment: It is not an update.. It is inserting a record. @AD.Net

Comment: sorry my bad, too tired :(

Comment: This is correct. You can't insert using VALUES WHERE a condition is true. The rows you are inserting are the new rows... you can, however, INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT Stuff FROM Crap WHERE Thingy=1;

Comment: Agreed @Robert Columbia