# error in SQL syntax at line '1' using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, syntax-error

i have the following error in the **Update code** :

> *You* *have* *an* *error* *in* *your* *SQL* *syntax;* *check* *the manual* *that* *corresponds* *to* *your* *MSQL* *server* *version* *for* *the* *right* *syntax* *to* _use _near'(where Aid ='3'*at line '1'*
>   Here is the code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 

    { 

        try 

        { 

            //This is my connection string i have assigned the database file address path 

            string MyConnection2 = "datasource=localhost;port=3307;username=root;password=root"; 

            //This is my update query in which i am taking input from the user through windows forms and update the record. 

            string Query = "update aircraft.l1201 set Name='" + this.nameTextBox.Text + "',Initials='" + this.piniTextBox.Text + "', where Aid='" + this.AidTextBox.Text + "';"; 

            //This is  MySqlConnection here i have created the object and pass my connection string. 

            MySqlConnection MyConn2 = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection2); 

            MySqlCommand MyCommand2 = new MySqlCommand(Query, MyConn2); 

            MySqlDataReader MyReader2; 

            MyConn2.Open(); 

            MyReader2 = MyCommand2.ExecuteReader(); 

            MessageBox.Show("Data Updated"); 

            while (MyReader2.Read()) 

            { 



            } 

            MyConn2.Close();//Connection closed here 

        } 

        catch (Exception ex) 

        { 



            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 

        } 

    }
```

Comment: Please format your post. It shows some effort on your side.

Comment: Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/a/30367283/34092 re: SQL injection. It won't solve your problem today - but it will save you a lifetime of pain later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma

```
... , where Aid=...
    ^---here
```

And you should really use Prepared Statements instead of patching your query together like this. And it would be way more secure too.