# C# SQL Select a data from table

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a database(username(key),Fullname,Pass), I want to search for the username and write out the Fullname for this username in a console.
I have these:

```
static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
static SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""path\login.mdf"";Integrated Security=True");

con.Open();
string username="mate";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Nev FROM Login WHERE username='" + username+ "'", con);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        string fullname;
        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")then?
```

"Nev" means Full name

I want it to write the Fullname into the "fullname" string, then just:

```
Console.Writeline("Welcome {0}",fullname);
```

Can you help me with this code?
I just don't know how to continue my code. Users can login and register to the app, and when they login i want to greet them like "Hello FullName"  when they register their username, fullname and password is stored, and they login with username & pass. I just don't know how to find the Fullname if i know the username. (I'm a beginner in SQL)

Comment: You don't seem to have opened a connection.

Comment: Just missed a line, there's a con.open @chaosifier

Comment: What is your question? What is the specific problem you are having? This should be in the body of the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why are you using DataAdapter? you just want to get ONE username, yes? Then use ExecuteScalar (it will directly return the string you need, and it's much faster)

Comment: So you want to know how to get the Fullname from the DataTable?

Comment: I just don't know how to continue my code. Users can login and register to the app, and when they login i want to greet them like "Hello FullName" @jdv

Comment: Exactly! if i know the username @chaosifier

Comment: @Skickpause you should **update the body of the question with these details**

Comment: @RenatoAfonso yes, when they register their username, fullname and password is stored, and they login with username & pass. I just don't know how to find the Fullname if i know the username. (I'm a beginner in SQL)

Comment: You should not concatenate a SQL statement like that especially if the value you are concatenating with (username) comes from user input it leaves you open to SQL injection.  you should use parameters.  An in the case you are looking for a single distinct value you can use ExecteScalar.   There are a lot of examples of this on SO

Comment: one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i.  Without parameters someone could literally drop all of your data, delete users, delete databases, and worse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after:

```
string fullname = null;
using(var con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""path\login.mdf"";Integrated Security=True")) {
    string username = "mate";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nev FROM Login WHERE username=@Username", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);

    con.open();
    fullname = cmd.ExecuteScalar()?.ToString();
}

if (fullname == null) {
    Console.WriteLine("The username could not be found!");
}
```

The `using` ensures that the connection is cleaned up once the block is exited. Also, you should use `Parameters` to be more resilient to SQL injection.

Comment: System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll - app goes to break mode"

Comment: Are you sure your connection string ("Data Source=(LocalDB)..." is correct?

Comment: Now it is. But still " 
Object reference not set to any object instance."

Comment: @Skickpause Are you absolutely certain that there is a username `'mate'` in your database? To me it sounds like the query isn't returning any results, so `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` is coming back null.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qfDtL I am 1000% sure. or is it a problem that the database is in the other project's folder? But the connection string is correct

Comment: @Skickpause Hmm. I have an idea, try removing the single quotes `'` around `@Username` in the SQL: `"SELECT Nev FROM Login WHERE username=@Username"`. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: YES. YOU'RE AWESOME :D

Comment: one more question. if i use parameters like this. the this can't be hacked with sql injection, right?

Comment: Yeah, parameterization is the safer way to put input into SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892205/2329708

Answer (score 0):

For your specific problem, try this code:

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      fullname = dt.Rows[0]["Nev"].ToString();
```

But here's a better and complete solution to your problem:

```
string userName = "mate";
string fullName = string.Empty;

string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=path\login.mdf;Initial Catalog=Login;Integrated Security=True";
string query = "SELECT Nev FROM Login WHERE username=@UserName;";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
     command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
     command.Parameters["@UserName"].Value = userName;

     try
     {
         connection.Open();
         fullName = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     }
}

Console.WriteLine("Hello {0}!", fullName);
```

Comment: Object reference not set to any object instance. "Hello !'

Comment: What connection string have you used? It seems that you've been using an incorrect connection string.

Comment: No, it can't be incorrect. I checked it a thousand times

Comment: Are you sure there's data in the table?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/qfDtL I am 1000% sure. or is it a problem that the database is in the other project's folder? But the connection string is correct

Comment: I think the problem is indeed in your connection string. You haven't specified the database to use. Set the Initial Catalog value to Login in the connection string.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the connection string. Please have a look. @Skickpause

Comment: The single quotes were the problem :) anyway. thank you all

Comment: No problem mate. Happy coding!