# Can I still use parameters for sql command?

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, sql-injection

Im trying to make a generic code for building Insert/Update query. So far i have only created the Update query, but i'mhaving doubts considering SQL injection.

My primary target is trying to create code to decrease the time of retyping the same code over and over.

```
public SqlConnection SqlConn;
private SqlCommand SqlComm;

public void UpdateRow(string TableName, string UpdateCondition, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> FieldAndValueList)
{
  SqlOpen();
  try
  {
    string UpdateString = $"UPDATE {TableName} ";
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> FieldAndValue in FieldAndValueList)
    {
      if (counter > 0) { UpdateString += "," };
      UpdateString += $"SET {FieldAndValue.Key} = {FieldAndValue.Value} ";
      Counter += 1;
    }
    if (UpdateCondition.Trim() != "") { UpdateString += $"WHERE {UpdateCondition};"; }
    SqlComm = SqlConn.CreateCommand();
    SqlComm.CommandText = UpdateString;
    SqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery;
  }
  catch { ShowError(); }
  finally { SqlClose(); } 
}
```

It would then be executed like so:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> UpdateValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>;
UpdateValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("age", txtAge.text)); 
UpdateRow("user", "user_id = X", UpdateValues);
```

Im trying to create it so SQL injection is not possible.

Comment: Your code is not safe. Use Parameters, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> == {"myField", "123; delete from table myTable; --"}` The text created will be `update SomeTable set myField = 123; delete from table myTable; -- UpdateCondition`, you'll update `SomeTable` and clear `MyTable`

Comment: @Ian, I already had my doubt about it not being safe. But i cant find out how to actually make it safe. This method makes the size of the update statement variable Im looking for a way to handle parameters while keeping the variable size of the update statement.

Comment: @Roberto: where is the *user input* (i.e. arbitrary, potentially malicious strings)  in the routine? Is it `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` only?

Comment: The name/values is one thing - that is solvable; however, your `UpdateCondition` is just ... no, you can't do that safely, ever

Comment: The UpdateCondition would be hardcoded from the actual form. Only the List would be altered by UseInput. (or at least the values will be). The size of list will change depending of form.

Comment: additional note: `FieldAndValueList` as a `<string,string>` is *also* probably a very bad idea, unless all the values **are strings**. That isn't the way to do data, basically. If the value is a `float`, **send it as a `float`** - otherwise, you can get into a *lot* of problems with conversions, including things like date formats, and different (international) representations of numbers (commas vs periods, etc)

Comment: The application I was working on, was only using int, string and bool as input values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to create it so SQL injection is not possible.

Then you **must** use parameters; for the individual fields, something like the following would work:

```cs
if (counter > 0) { sb.Append(","); }
var pName = "@p" + counter.ToString();
sb.Append("[").Append(FieldAndValue.Key).Append("]=").Append(pName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(pName, ((object)FieldAndValue.Value) ?? DBNull.Value);
Counter += 1;
```

where `sb` is a `StringBuilder` (to avoid too many string concatenations)

However! Your planned `string UpdateCondition` is inherently not solvable. That **cannot** be made injection-safe. You need to think of a better way of doing that.

Or, better: use any off-the-shelf ORM.

Comment: Hallo Marc, Ill try this. As for the Condition. Its hardcoded from the form that actually calls the function. So no user input.

Comment: @Roberto just to emphasize: the last line in the answer is my strong recommendation; IMO you're going to get yourself into a lot of nasty holes trying to re-invent this stuff

Comment: Guess i was looking from the wrong angle as i couldnt find that. But it's more that im trying to get back into C# (havent done anything for 2y as i have been doing Delphi). But i'll have a look into it.