# Is Oracle do parameters prevent SQL injection?

Tags: .net, oracle, sql-injection

In SQL Server, I know parameter can prevent SQL Injection with detail reason from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892166/how-does-sqlparameter-prevent-sql-injection), and is Oracle the same can prevent SQL injection by using parameters?

This is my C# code:

```
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(querySql);
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Column1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 3, "Value1", ParameterDirection.Input));
command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Column1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 6, "Value1", ParameterDirection.Input));
cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Yes, SQL injection is a **general** problem for any database system that uses SQL as it's query language - it's **not** specific to SQL Server..... and the solution of using **parametrized queries** is also generally the best accepted practice to avoid SQL injection

Comment: ok, if there's Oracle Master that can explain working detail in Oracle is appreciated by readers.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, one method is to use Pipelined Functions - essentially parameterized views of the data. See here for detailed explanation and examples:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/addci/using-pipelined-and-parallel-table-functions.html#GUID-EFB94CFB-3E44-4236-B490-ADBB480C94D4
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

The documentation also talks about SQL Injection, how it works, and how to defend against it:

- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-1E31057E-057F-4A53-B1DD-8BC2C337AA2C
- https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/overview/how-to-write-injection-proof-plsql-1-129572.pdf
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2